# How to get window.document from selenium driver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium driver object. But I need DOM object how to get window.document?

I tried my covering pageSource to DOM object but it's not working as expected.

```
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

How to get window.document object from driver ?